# What to do about [activemq] and [activemq-artemis]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

[activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq):

> Apache ActiveMQ "Classic" is an open source (Apache 2.0 licensed) message broker which fully implements the Java Message Service 1.1 (JMS). It provides "Enterprise Features" like clustering, multiple message stores, and ability to use any database as a JMS persistence provider besides VM, cache, and journal persistency.

[activemq-artemis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq-artemis)

> Apache ActiveMQ® Artemis is an asynchronous messaging broker, an example of Message Oriented Middleware.

Sounds like [ActiveMQ® Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) is a "next-generation" replacement for [ActiveMQ "Classic"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/).  Since they're both called "ActiveMQ", having the [activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq) tag refer to only one of those is confusing.

What should we do about this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to simply rename [activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq) to [activemq-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq-classic), with no synonym.

That leaves both tag names unambiguous.

---

As of 2024-02-23, this is now done.

```
updating post history, 6702 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 5716 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'activemq-classic' doesn't exist, renaming 'activemq' to 'activemq-classic'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [activemq-classic] and [activemq] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1465 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
1557 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: classic VS legacy. Hm. Well since they dub it classic themselves, I guess that one wins.

Comment: Although I don't believe it is strictly _necessary_, I'm fine with renaming the `activemq` tag to be `activemq-classic` in order to more clearly differentiate questions about ActiveMQ "Classic" from ActiveMQ Artemis (and its `activemq-artemis` tag).

Comment: I agree with this in principle, but I would bet real money that the original activemq tag will get recreated soon after.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas — and then the questions with the tag can be retagged so there are no questions left with the tag and it goes away again.  It also requires some reputation to be able to create tags.  Those with enough reputation to do so should know better and can be chastised if necessary.